# Force method to call base method from base class

Tags: c#, oop

If i am creating method with "override" property, derived method will not call base method implementation automatically and i will need to call it manually using "base" keyword like this:

```
public class A
{
    public virtual void Say()
    {
        Console.Write("A");
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public override void Say()
    {
        base.Say();
        Console.Write("B");
    }
}
```

So only in this case string "A" and "B" will be written to console. So the question is how can i get rid of "base.Say();" line? So i want to force every derived method "Say" to call base method from base class. Is it possible? I am looking for any solutions, even if i will be forced to use other keywords

Comment: This smells of the X-Y problem; a question on a proposed solution for an undefined problem. What is the true business requirement leading you to make this inquiry?

Comment: The short answer is: no.  It's not possible in the way you describe it.

Comment: I am asking about this question in general cause i had many cases in which using this feature was required

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Although it is not possible to achieve this directly, you could get the same effect by writing your own method that is *not* virtual, which calls the virtual after performing some fixed operation:

```
public class A
{
    public void Say()
    {
        Console.Write("A");
        SayImpl();
    }
    protected virtual void SayImpl()
    {
        // Do not write anything here:
        // for the base class the writing is done in Say()
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    protected override void SayImpl()
    {
        Console.Write("B");
    }
}
```

Now any class inheriting from `A` and implementing `SayImpl()` would have `A` prepended to its printout.

Comment: Thanks! But i am curious why c# developers didn't add feature to override mathod with implementation? That is very good feature, i require it many times

Comment: @Eugen1344: That's exactly what C# supports already.  Now, automatically calling the base class's method also as part of the override, that's a different story.  And then you would have to consider that not all developers want that behavior out-of-the-box.  Plus, what if you want the call to the base method to happen AFTER instead of BEFORE the override.  Or what about in the middle, or based on a condition.  Keeping it explicit is the best and most flexible option.

Comment: If you require this many times, then you have an interesting set of requirements. I have very rarely needed to dictate how callers call base methods. Also, the tact that there is such an easy workaround is a great reason to not create a special feature for it. Features cost money.

Comment: @Eric This depends on the design. I didn't make it abstract to mimic the hierarchy from the post, but in general I prefer making all my non-leaf classes `abstract` (and all my leaf classes `sealed`).

Comment: @sstan i think is it possible to create new keyword. For example "extended". So you will write "public extended void Say()" to make this method extend method from base class